How to connect (or export to JSON) a salvaged MongoDB database
In the wake of the catastrophic failure of an upgrade to my self-hosted Wekan instance, I have salvaged the /var/lib/mongodb directory where Wekan's data was stored, and downloaded it to my laptop. This is for MongoDB Community Edition v6.0.
I'd like to either (1) connect MongoDB to this salvaged data, or (2) convert the data to JSON or some other human readable format. I've installed MongoDB 6.0 on my laptop, but haven't looked at Mongo in years, and my naïve attempts to access the salvaged data have been unsuccessful.
Anyone have an idea about how to do this, if it's even possible?


Is the version installed (v. 6.0) the same as that of the database? 2. Have you tested creating a small new db and connecting to it? 3. Have you tried the tutorials at https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/tutorials/connect/ and https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/mongo/? 4. Do you have the correct authentication info?


@DrMoishePippik 1. Yes; 2. No; 3. No; 4. Probably. I'll revisit once I've moved these all to 'Yes'.

Turns out it was a v5.0 database, not v6.0 after all. Once I downgraded to v5.0 I was able to connect to it and export the collections as JSON or CSV (using mongoexport).
